# How to solve Blackjack using Dynamic Programming?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization, blackjack

This question is from the book [Daily Coding Problem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1793296634), and is a slightly modified version of the problem described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENyox7kNKeY) MIT video. The question is as follows:

> Blackjack is a two player card game whose rules are as follows:
>
> - The player and then the dealer are each given two cards.
> - The player can then "hit", or ask for arbitrarily many additional cards, so as his or her total does not exceed 21.
> - The dealer must then hit if his or her total is 16 or lower, otherwise pass.
> - Finally, the two compare totals, and the one with the greatest sum not exceeding 21 is the winner.
>
> For this problem, we simplify the card values to be as follows: each
> card between 2 and 10 counts as their face value, face cards count as
> 10, and aces count as 1.
>
> Given perfect knowledge of the sequence of cards in the deck,
> implement a blackjack solver that maximizes the player's score (that
> is, wins minus losses).

The book has the following code:

```
import random


class Deck:
    def __init__(self, seed=None):
        self.cards = [i for i in range(1, 10)] * 4 + [10] * 16
        random.seed(seed)
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, start, n):
        return self.cards[start:start + n]


class Player:
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.hand = hand
        self.total = 0

    def deal(self, cards):
        self.hand.extend(cards)
        self.total = sum(self.hand)


def cmp(x, y):
    return (x > y) - (x < y)


def play(deck, start, scores):
    player = Player(deck.deal(start, 2))
    dealer = Player(deck.deal(start + 2, 2))
    results = []

    for i in range(49 - start):
        count = start + 4
        player.deal(deck.deal(count, i))
        count += i

        if player.total > 21:
            results.append((-1, count))
            break

        while dealer.total < 17 and count < 52:
            dealer.deal(deck.deal(count, 1))
            count += 1
        if dealer.total > 21:
            results.append((1, count))
        else:
            results.append((cmp(player.total, dealer.total), count))

    options = []
    for score, next_start in results:
        options.append(score +
                       scores[next_start] if next_start <= 48 else score)
    scores[start] = max(options)


def blackjack(seed=None):
    deck = Deck(seed)
    scores = [0 for _ in range(52)]

    for start in range(48, -1, -1):
        play(deck, start, scores)

    return scores[0]
```

Basically, for a suffix of the deck starting at card `n` (1 <= n <= 52), the code tries out all possibilities of the player taking `0` to `52 - n` hits, until they go bust, and then the dealer taking hits as long as their score is <= 16.

For each iteration of the loop `for i in range(49 - start)`, the `count` = "number of cards used" is reset to `start + 4`, which makes sense since we are simulating the player taking a different number of hits than last time. However, **what troubles me is the player and the dealer's hands are not reset**. In my mind, for each iteration of that loop, we should start with the player and dealer having been dealt two cards each, and not retain the last hand.

Am I understanding this right?